# Disable links till all animations stop and enable them again

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image slider like animation, the differences is that in one slide are several elements, in my case 4 pictures which come from the left or right side in the scene.

The question is how to make the links that trigger the animation function to be disabled until the animation is finished 100%, and then enable again.

Here is my code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//
$('.package_box_menu li').children().click(function(){

    $(this).showProducts($(this).attr("id"))

});

jQuery.fn.showProducts = function (clickedSeason) {

    var nextToShowSide = $('.'+[clickedSeason]+'_img1').attr("rel");            
    var active = $('img[ rel |= active]').attr('season');

    if (nextToShowSide == 'right') {var whereTo = '-1000px'; var currentToHideSide ="left" };
    if (nextToShowSide == 'left') {var whereTo = '3000px'; var currentToHideSide ="right" };    

    show();
    hide(active, whereTo, currentToHideSide);

    function show(){

        var allToShow = ($('img[ season |= '+[clickedSeason]+']').get()).length;            
        for (var i = 1; i<= allToShow ; i++){
            var delay =  $('.'+[clickedSeason]+'_img'+[i]).attr('delay');
            var position = $('.'+[clickedSeason]+'_img'+[i]).attr('left');
            $('.'+[clickedSeason]+'_img'+[i]).stop().delay(delay).animate({'margin-left': position }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo').attr('rel','active');            
        }       
    };


    function hide(active, whereTo, currentToHideSide){

        var all = ($('img[ rel |= active]').get()).length;
        for (var i = 1; i<= all ; i++){
            if ($('.'+[active]+'_img'+[i]).attr('rel') == 'active') {
                $('.'+[active]+'_img'+[i]).stop().delay([i]+'00').animate({'margin-left': whereTo }, 1000, 'easeInExpo').attr('rel', currentToHideSide );
            }
        } 

    };

};

jQuery().showProducts('spring');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are just trying to make sure a link isn't clicked while being animated add this to your click.

```
$('.package_box_menu li').children().click(function(){
    if($('img[class$=img1]').is(':animated')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

    $(this).showProducts($(this).attr("id"));

});
```

This will simply refuse the click while it animated and then work when it stops. *$(this) could be replaced with something that is being animated for example your slide* :)

**NOTE**

As there is no HTML shown I had to make some assumptions on the selector i used 'img[class$=img1]' which is a img where the class ends in 'img1' taken from the `'_img1').attr("rel");`

Copied your site to Fiddle and got it working with the change i mentions [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qE4Vc/)

Comment: +1: I always forget this method and use a tedious mutex variable to reset into the animation callback.

Comment: @AbstractChaos If you look better to the script you`ll see that not the button(link) is what animates. ...

Comment: @NoBine Which is why i said in the comment below the code chunk that it could be replaced with your slide. I will show you as it werent obvious

Comment: @AbstractChaos - Maybe I`m not to clear. Please take a look at [link](http://doina.greenapplestudio.eu/)

Comment: @NoBine Move $(this).showProducts($(this).attr("id")) to underneath the if statement the return false stops it being executed but it above it so its executed first.

Comment: @AbstractChaos It`s working but if you click like " crazy ", the "presentation" will not show good. Do you have any idea how can I use .bind() and .unbind() instead is(':animated') is this not a better idea ?!?

Comment: is there anybody who can give me an idea of how to use .bind() in my example ?